# how to keep new lines after moving an element up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the example below click on `dolor` so it becomes active
then click on button - and `dolor` is moved up
but in the resulting html - the new line is missing

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ati', function(){
    $('.aact').removeClass('aact');
    $(this).addClass('aact');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    let tg = $('.aact');
    if(tg.length == 0){alert('TITLE IS NOT SELECTED');return;}
    let tgg = tg.prev();
    tg.insertBefore(tgg);
    let a = $('#awrap').html();
    console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.aact{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="awrap" id='awrap'>
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati">ipsum</div>
<div class="ati">dolor</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

result after button click:

```
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati aact">dolor</div><div class="ati">ipsum</div>
```

what I need is:

```
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati aact">dolor</div>
<div class="ati">ipsum</div>
```

how to get this ?

Comment: What does the OP need the new line for? In terms of markup and its semantics this information is not necessarily needed. And in terms of UI one might rather rely on proper css rules.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - I need to save `awrap` html as a new  file and want to keep new lines just for better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the newline the OP wants to insert, it can be done by creating and inserting a text node like ...

```
$(document.createTextNode('\n')).insertBefore(tgg);
```

... which changes the OP's code to ...

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ati', function(){
  $('.aact').removeClass('aact');
  $(this).addClass('aact');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  let tg = $('.aact');

  if (tg.length === 0) {
    alert('TITLE IS NOT SELECTED');
    return;
  }
  let tgg = tg.prev();
  tg.insertBefore(tgg);

  $(document.createTextNode('\n')).insertBefore(tgg);

  let a = $('#awrap').html();

  console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.aact { background: orange; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 110px!important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="awrap" id='awrap'>
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati">ipsum</div>
<div class="ati">dolor</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

But the result still might not satisfy the OP since the OP wants/needs ...

> *"[...] to save `awrap` html as a new file and want[s] to keep new lines just for better readability"*.

The latter sounds more like a sanitizing tasks where a regex based approach might be suited best.

One would go for 2 text replacements where the first one matches any closing or empty tag including an optional trailing sequence of newline characters ... [`/(<\/[^>]+>|<[^\/]+\/>)\n*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/DzmYt2/1) ... and the second trims any leading sequence of newline characters ... [`/^\n+/`](https://regex101.com/r/DzmYt2/2) ... from the markup string.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ati', function(){
  $('.aact').removeClass('aact');
  $(this).addClass('aact');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  let tg = $('.aact');

  if (tg.length === 0) {
    alert('TITLE IS NOT SELECTED');
    return;
  }
  let tgg = tg.prev();
  tg.insertBefore(tgg);

  let a = $('#awrap')
    .html()
    .replace(/(<\/[^>]+>|<[^\/]+\/>)\n*/g, '$1\n')
    .replace(/^\n+/, '');

  console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.aact { background: orange; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 110px!important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="awrap" id='awrap'>
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati">ipsum</div>
<div class="ati">dolor</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ati', function(){
    $('.aact').removeClass('aact');
    $(this).addClass('aact');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    let tg = $('.aact');
    if(tg.length == 0){alert('TITLE IS NOT SELECTED');return;}
    let tgg = tg.prev();
    tg.insertBefore(tgg);
    $('.awrap').html($('.awrap').html().replace(/\n/g, ""));
    $('.ati').after("\n");
    let a = $('#awrap').html();
    console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.aact{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="awrap" id='awrap'>
<div class="ati">lorem</div>
<div class="ati">ipsum</div>
<div class="ati">dolor</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```